# Stop loop and start again from the beginning

Tags: swift, xcode, loops, sprite-kit

I am trying to include enumerateChildNode with a For Loop. My code is below.

```
func movement() {
scene?.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//enemy") {
(node, stop) in
  enemyArray.append(node as! SKSpriteNode)
}

for i in enemyArray {
if enemy.position = player.position + 1 {
player.position = player.position + 1
}
continue
}
```

What the code above does is check for every enemy SKSpriteNode on the screen (lets say it finds 6), and then checks their positions relative to the player. If the players position is near the enemy position, it moves the players position, and then continues the for loop from where it was and checks the players position from the remaining enemies.

However, if the player moves near an enemy position that the for loop already checked (which was false at the time), it will miss that the player is near that enemy. EG: The for loop checks enemies 1,2,3 (finds 3 is near player and moves the player near 2) then checks 4,5,6. It will miss 2...

What I want the code to do

```
 If enemy.position = player.position + 1 {
 //move player
 *stop the loop, and check the players position from the beginning of the for loop* 
}
```

Comment: Right now, this question is of limited use to future readers. I think it would help a lot if you included your complete issue, including how you intend to change `i`. That will invalidate the current answer, which is usually discouraged. In this case, though, I personally think it's a necessary improvement to your question.

Comment: In your example `position` seems to be one-dimensional so it can be sorted and then you  could perhaps use a more intelligent approach when it comes to determine what happens when you move the player.

Comment: I think you're right. I'll need a different approach :( The position isn't the problem, its checking all the enemy position's again after I move the player which I need to think about. Maybe a for loop isn't the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Call the method again and break out of the loop. But, this causes an infinite loop as you know while posting your question. Not sure how you're planning on changing the value of "i" since it's scope is within the method. Anyways here's how you achieve this:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
movement()

func movement() {
    for i in array {
        if i == 3 {
            print("hi")
            movement()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: stack overflow? It will never reach the `break`.

Comment: Thanks Frankenstein. While what you wrote was correct, my idea how how it would work was wrong. It crashes due to infinite loop (obviously). I have updated my question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ya lol, you're right unless OP could change "i" somehow, which is unlikely.

Comment: @Questions Just saw the updated post, probably should try a different approach for your problem, maybe sort it like Joakim has said.